# Trying to collapse certain tables not all tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that currently collapses all rows except for a title row. How do I only target tables that I want to collapse? (e.g. any table with the class no-collapse, should not collapse)

JQUERY:

```
$('tbody > tr:not(".collapse")').hide();
$('.collapse').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.collapse').toggle();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e8jeb5me/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line to:

```
$('table:not(".no-collapse") tbody > tr:not(".collapse")').hide();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e8jeb5me/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You already have similar logic in your selectors. Just add `table:not(.no-collapse)`.

e.g.

```
$('table:not(.no-collapse) tbody > tr:not(".collapse")').hide();
$('.collapse').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.collapse').toggle();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/e8jeb5me/4/